# Edit VBA code that Consolidates Workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro here that consolidates all files into a master file. Currently this copies the entire worksheet from each file and stacks it into the master file. This ideal code will go into source file and find the header row and copy below. The header row is not static. Sometimes its on Row 5, sometimes row 15. There is data above the header and its usually long text strings.

How do I edit the below code to do that?

### Thanks In Advance!

**Here is the Code:**

---

```
 Sub Consolidate_BST()

 Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
 Dim FolderPath As String
 Dim NRow As Long
 Dim FileName As String
 Dim WorkBk As Workbook
 Dim sourceRange As Range
 Dim destrange As Range

 Worksheets("Consolidate BSts").Range("A1:J50000").ClearContents
 Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 ' Create a new workbook and set a variable to the first sheet.
 Set SummarySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Consolidate BSts")

 ' Modify this folder path to point to the files you want to use. 'M
 FolderPath = "C:\Users\413315\Documents\\March Bluesheets"

 ' NRow keeps track of where to insert new rows in the destination workbook.
 NRow = 1

 ' Call Dir the first time, pointing it to all Excel files in the folder path.
 FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xl*")

 ' Loop until Dir returns an empty string.
 Do While FileName <> ""
 ' Open a workbook in the folder
 Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)

 ' Set the cell in column A to be the file name.
 SummarySheet.Range("A" & NRow).Value = FileName

 ' Modify this range for your workbooks.
 ' It can span multiple rows.
 Set sourceRange = WorkBk.Worksheets("Regional Estimates").Range("B3:J1000")

 ' Set the destination range to start at column B and
 ' be the same size as the source range.
 Set destrange = SummarySheet.Range("B" & NRow)
 Set destrange = destrange.Resize(sourceRange.Rows.Count, _
 sourceRange.Columns.Count)

 ' Copy over the values from the source to the destination.
 destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

 ' Increase NRow so that we know where to copy data next.
 NRow = NRow + destrange.Rows.Count

 ' Close the source workbook without saving changes.
 WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False

 ' Use Dir to get the next file name.
 FileName = Dir()
 Loop


 SummarySheet.Columns.AutoFit
 Worksheets("Consolidate BSts").Range("D2:D50000").ClearContents


 End Sub
```

Comment: So visually how do you identify the header row?

Comment: I know the name of each column as header. Ex. Series is in column 1, Date Exception is Column 2 etc...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the header is always in the same column, you could add something like the following to the top of your code:

```
Dim cond As Boolean
Dim headerRow As Integer, i As Integer
cond = False

While cond <> True

    i = i + 1
    If sourceRange.Cells(i, 1) = "Name of Header" Then     'For a header in column A
        i = headerRow                                         
        cond = True
    End If
Wend
```

Then with you should be able to modify the range of data that it intakes based on what row the headers are in.

Also you could change the if statement to something more general, but it's hard to know what it should be without knowing what your headers and data look like.